# @stack & @push not working in Laravel Livewire 3

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

@stack & @push not working in Laravel Livewire 3

At first, I added @stack('scripts') in livewire 3 layout file
Then, I added @push('scripts') in my view file. But this script isn't showing on the rendered page.

```
@push('scripts')
<script>alert('Hello')</script>
@endpush
```

What's the issue? I didn't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply upgrade your Livewire 3 version to a stable one.